# reduce redundant data in pandas rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   name    course   score
0  jhin      math     100
1  jhin   physics      90
2  jhin   chinese      95
3  lisa      math     100
4  lisa   physics      90
5  lisa   chinese      95
```

What I want is like this:

```
   name   math   physics   chinese
0  jhin    100        90        95
1  lisa    100        90        95
```

This is a demonstration of what I want to do, what's more, I want to fill empty cells of columns `math`, `physics` and `chinese` with certain value, such as `None`

Any help would be greatly appreciated ;-)

Comment: there must be a solution already but my English is quite poor and I don't know how to describe it precisely in Google to retrieve an answer ;-(

Comment: `df.groupby(['name', 'course'])['score'].first().unstack()`